# Condition not being evaluated as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code that acts as a listener of a button and evaluates whether some fields above this button are filled in:

```
def goListener(self):
    if all( [self.nme.get() != "", self.dsc.get() != "", self.imp.get != ""] ):
        name = self.nme.get()
        desc = self.dsc.get()
        while True:
            try:
                imp = int(self.imp.get())
                break
            except:
                imp = int(self.imp.get())
```

When I run this program with different fields filled in or otherwise, it gets it right and produces the error message I ask it to with every combination except where nme and dsc are filled in but imp isn't, this produces the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\todo.py", line 68, in goListener
    imp = int(self.imp.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is running the except block by the way, which it shouldn't. Is this a problem with the evaluation, or am I missing something here?

Comment: The end of your 2nd line should probably be ...`self.imp.get()`, not `self.imp.get`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
self.imp.get != ""
```

You are failing to invoke the `.get()` method. Try:

```
self.imp.get() != ""
```

Answer (score 3):

If `imp = int(self.imp.get())` throws an error, calling it again outside of a `try` block will throw the same error.

The `except` block is for code that should run when there is an exception:

```
        try:
            imp = int(self.imp.get())
            break
        except:
            print "Something bad happened"
```